# ELK - How to provide permission to individual user on particular index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have few index in my cluster

index_2019-01-01

index_2019-01-02

index_2019-01-03

index_2019-01-04

index_2019-01-05

index_2019-01-06

There are two user USER1 & USER2

USER1 has full right to this index pattern.

I want to provide access rigths to USER2 for first three index only.

How can I achieve this in ELK

Elastic version 7.2

Answer (score 1):

This feature (index level security) is not possible with the basic license of elasticsearch.

But there are several other ways to archieve it with more or less invest of money and/or time:

1. Obtain a Subscription for  Elasticsearch containing Index level security [elasticsearch security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html)
2. Use 3rd party plugins like [readonlyrest](https://readonlyrest.com/) or [search guard](https://search-guard.com/)
3. Add a separate security layer in front of your cluster using a reverse proxy (apache httpd, nginx,... ) and further configuration or even a homebrew proxy api

Have fun!

Comment: I will try these above approaches to achieve the same. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking about Elastic v7.2, but I stumbled upon this question and I'm using ES v8.4.1. In case someone else ends up here from a Google search, I want to say that it's very much possible to do what OP wants.

I'll assume that the built-in user `elastic` has the password '123456', which you can set via `ELASTIC_PASSWORD: 123456` in `docker-compose.yml` if you're using Docker ([link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/create-user-in-elasticsearch/182401)).

If you're using Docker, exec into the elasticsearch Docker container via `docker exec -it elasticsearch bash`. Here are the steps to enable index-level access:

1. Create a role that has access to the desired indices:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_security/role/regular?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "cluster": ["all"],
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "index_2019-01-01", "index_2019-01-02", "index_2019-01-03"],
      "privileges": ["all"]
    }
  ]
}
' -u elastic:123456
```

2. Create a user with that role:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_security/user/john?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "password" : "123456",
  "roles" : [ "regular" ],
  "full_name" : "John John",
  "email" : "johnjohn@example.com",
  "metadata" : {
    "intelligence" : 7
  }
}
' -u elastic:123456
```

3. Now try fetching all the docs from any of the indexes that `john` has access to (you should see all the docs):
   `curl "localhost:9200/index_2019-01-01/_search?pretty=true" -u john:123456`
4. Also, try fetching the docs from an index that `john` doesn't have access to (you should receive a 403 HTTP status in the response):
   `curl "localhost:9200/index_2019-01-04/_search?pretty=true" -u john:123456`